# Fragment crash while switching between them quickly inside BottomNavigation

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I have my MainActivity inside which I have BottomNavigation which loads fragment with the following method

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I switch between them quickly my app crashes at various places, but when I go slowly one by one everything works fine

This is how my app structure looks like

[image]

I am using `Reteofit` for API call

I already tried `setuserVisibleHint` also check if my view rootView is created or not

Comment: share your logcat report

Comment: I can share logcat but the errors are not consistent they on fragment annd mostly are NPE

Comment: Seeing crash in logcat is essential part in finding the bug. And helping you.

Answer (score 0):

I was using retrofit to get a response of API then pass it to an adapter but due to fast switch using bottom navigation and fragments then my app crashing because the hideProgressBar() throw NullException. I observed that view is destroyed then widgets don't perform.

So I put check to make sure that view is not null. It fixes my situation. I hope it helps other people who are looking for the same solution.

> In Kotlin: view   and  Java: getView() (In Java)

[image]